# Get UIButton reference from viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am very new to iPhone development. I am trying to disable an already existing button but I cant actually obtain a pointer to a specific element in the view. For instance, I have the following in the viewController header

```
- (IBAction)one:(id)sender;
```

and the implementation is

```
- (IBAction)one:(id)sender {
```

}

which are just event handlers. However, I need disable the button when view opens and I am a little bit lost on how to obtain references to elements outside of the event handler.

So in other words, my thought is to have something like:

```
UIButton* myButton = //something
```

where the something is where I am lost on what to do. Any ideas? I greatly appreciate any help I get on here!

Comment: One way is to set tags to the button specific event & change when you want it..

Comment: on interface , from button's property , make it hidden

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a property for your button in the interface:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * button;
```

And add this to implementation:

```
@synthesize button;
```

Then connect the button to it in interface builder. After this you can disable the button by:

```
button.enabled = NO;
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot choose your answer for a few min, however one thing to add to this would be you need to @synthesize the variable in the implementation.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just give tag to your button and access your button with tag value.

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
[btn setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your .h File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface RpViewController : UIViewController

 @property (retain , nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *Btn1;

 @end
```

**In your .m file , in implementation write this :**

```
@synthesize Btn1;

Now on interface , click on button.
In button's properties - > Drawings - check   Hidden    checkbox.

Wherever you want to show that button , just write.



 [Btn1 setHidden:FALSE];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button;
@synthesize button;

// In View Did Load...
self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; // button can be of any type. 
[self.button setTag:1]; 
// if you have more buttons initialize it and set its tag. you can get to know which button was pressed using tags.

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void) buttonEvent:(UIButton *) sender
{
   NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);
    if(sender.tag == 1)
    {
      [self.button setEnabled:NO]; // This makes your button disabled, i.e you can see the button but you cannot click on it.
      [self.button setHidden:YES]; // This makes your button hidden.
     }
}
```

if you have more doubts ping me back.